# Source Generators for class library project in c#

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation, class-library, sourcegenerators

Is this possible to generate code with Source Generator in c# into class library project? I would like this auto-generated code to be packed into Nuget package then.

When I try to build a project made according to the Microsoft(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview) tutorial I encounter the following error:

> CSC : warning CS8785: Generator 'HelloSourceGenerator' failed to generate source. It will not contribute to the output and compilation errors may occur as a result. Exception was of type 'NullReferenceException' with message 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The only difference is that I am trying to generate code for a class library project, not a console application.

I tried to do it according to the guide posted on Microsoft's website(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview), but it assumes generating code for an application that has a console interface.

Comment: That sounds like your generator has a bug (throws that exception). A generator can work in any type of (C#) project

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I think my generator has no errors. I prepared two projects (one a console application, the other a class library) using the generator project in exactly the same way. The console project generates classes, while the library project does not.

Comment: @TheStix13 _"The console project generates classes, while the library project does not."_ - this does not prove that your source generator does not have a bug. Please share a [mre].

Comment: Solved! So, basically I was using template code without exactly knowing what is happening inside of it. Thank you @GuruStron! Your answer was very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have followed the docs to a tee, the following should be the issue:

```
// Find the main method
var mainMethod = context.Compilation.GetEntryPoint(context.CancellationToken);
```

As comment states this will find the main method which library project obviously does not have, so based on the [sources](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/8e4ab418a8f9703f7dfe3a66adc9b3876ef9382f/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Compilation/CSharpCompilation.cs#L1783) and [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.compilation.getentrypoint?view=roslyn-dotnet-4.7.0):

> Returns the Main method that will serves as the entry point of the assembly, if it is executable (and not a script).

`mainMethod` will be null, hence the exception you see. Usually you want to analyze assembly for some syntax, for example as I do in [my currently unfinished generator](https://github.com/gurustron/default-record-ctor/tree/main):

```
public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context)
{
    context.RegisterForSyntaxNotifications(() => new RecordSyntaxReceiver());
}
```

Code for receiver [can be found here](https://github.com/gurustron/default-record-ctor/blob/main/src/SoCSharp.Generators.RecordDefaultCtor/RecordSyntaxReceiver.cs).

Also I highly recommend to go through the linked in the docs [Source Generator Samples @github](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-sdk/blob/main/samples/CSharp/SourceGenerators/SourceGeneratorSamples/AutoNotifyGenerator.cs) and [Source Generators Cookbook](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/source-generators.cookbook.md).

Comment: Another common way is to define an attribute and look for its usage, like the MVVM source generators or the AutoBindable generator do.